# Can anyone tell me why my Scrollspy is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building my own website and trying to implement a bootstrap scrollspy to the site, but I just can't get it to work. 
Please help me out with this.
I will add the code from my test page.
This is how far I have progressed:

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Die 3 Meta-Tags oben *müssen* zuerst im head stehen; jeglicher  sonstiger head-Inhalt muss *nach* diesen Tags kommen -->
<title>Bootstrap-Basis-Vorlage</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
    body{position: relative;}
    #test1{
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #test3{
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #test2{
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollspytest">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="navbar-brand">TEST</div>
        </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="scrollspytest" >
          <ul id="navleiste"class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a id="home"  href="#test1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="about" href="#test2">About</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="test1"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
<script>
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#scrollspytest' })
</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Working good here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjBYVZ

Comment: well that is a good question i will post my whole code again

Comment: You have to load Bootstrap JS file after jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `bootstrap.min.js`, and you should add it (right) after `jquery.min.js`.

The example below is from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) and as you can see, they have done exactly the same thing.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 body {
  position: relative;
}
#section1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}
#section2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #673ab7;
}
#section3 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
#section41 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
#section42 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #009688;
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>></script>

</body>
```